# how i can check multiple keys in List< keyvaluepair <string,string>>?

Tags: c#, string

i have a list of keyvaluepair in c# and i want to check two keys means return true if both exist in all other it's return false.

can someone tell em how i can do this through writing one statement only like my code not worked in c#

```
(info.Exists(x => x.Key == "user" && x.Key == "pass"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
if (info.Any(x => x.Key == "user") && info.Any(x => x.Key == "pass"))
```

(I've used `Any` here so that it's more general to any `IEnumerable<T>` using LINQ, but you could use `Exists` for `List<T>` just as easily.)

Just as a fun alternative:

```
string[] requiredKeys = { "user, "pass" };
if (!requiredKeys.Except(info.Select(x => x.Key)).Any())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You beat me by 19 seconds. Close race :) (and almost character by character answers).